# How to import sub-module from a sub-module

Tags: python

I ran into a problem with imports. I want to import the sub-module (module/hello2) into other sub-module (module/hello1).
Here's the code of module/hello1/**init**.py:

```
import hello2

hello2.function()
```

Here's the code of module/hello2/**init**.py:

```
def function():
    print("Hello!")
```

The problem that PyCharm shows that it's wrong way.
How to import module relatively?

**UPDATE:** Question closed. I did some experiments with the package. PyCharm didn't know about that package so it threw the "dependecy cannot be fullfilled" error.
I did so:

```
from .. import hello2
```

**UPDATE 2:** It's my fault. Something happened that PyCharm started detecting package correctly.

Comment: `import module.hello2 as hello2` or `from .hello2 import function`

Comment: from hello2 import function